# sqlite3 linking problems

Tags: sqlite

I'm having troubling linking a program with sqlite3.  Any ideas?

```
gcc -g -O2 main.o work.o uuid.o sqlite3.o -lboost_system -lboost_thread -o server
sqlite3.o: In function `unixDlError':
/home/matt/dev/serv/sqlite3.c:27231: undefined reference to `dlerror'
sqlite3.o: In function `unixDlSym':
/home/matt/dev/serv/sqlite3.c:27258: undefined reference to `dlsym'
sqlite3.o: In function `unixDlClose':
/home/matt/dev/serv/sqlite3.c:27262: undefined reference to `dlclose'
sqlite3.o: In function `unixDlOpen':
/home/matt/dev/serv/sqlite3.c:27217: undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I would think that you would want to link in the library, not the object file. Did you try `-llibsqlite3`?

Comment: Thanks msw, thats actually correct as well and works.

Comment: That looks like a program that's using a bundled copy of the sqlite3 amalgmation - `-lsqlite3` (surely not `-llibsqlite3`, that would be liblibsqlite3.a/.so) will pick up a *different* copy (the system one, which, alas, may not be the one the program needs).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tack an -ldl on there after -lboost_thread.