# What is the easiest way to use Sqlite in D program on Ubuntu?

Tags: sqlite, d

I suppose using `phobos.etc.c.sqlite3` binding. Compiling sqlite3.c using a C compiler to make a .o file and then link it with my program.

Which C compiler should I use, and what compiler flags?
Is it possible link the sqlite3.o with DMD in one step, without calling linker separately?

Or is there some other even easier way?

**Answer: How to get Sqlite going with D on 64bit Ubuntu**

1. install sqlite dev `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`
2. compile `dmd test.d -L-ldl -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a`

test.d

```
import std.stdio, std.string, etc.c.sqlite3;

void main () {
    sqlite3* db;
    auto ret = sqlite3_open (toStringz("mydb.s3db"), &db);
    writeln (ret);
}
```

-ldl switch was needed because of [sqlite3 linking problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455202/sqlite3-linking-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the binding with an available `sqlite` library (of an appropriate version, certainly), without having to manually compile it to an object file. Just like what you would have done in C: you'd `#include <headers>` and add `-llibrary` to compiler flags. The same here — `import`, and a link directive.

EDIT:

On Ubuntu you can install precompiled `sqlite` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Also, see http://prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?DatabaseBindings#SQLite for some other `sqlite` binding variants.

Comment: What is the "available sqlite library"?

Comment: I mean a binary static or dynamic library, available online (http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) or via the package manager of your system. I.e. you might or might not compile it yourself if you need to, but it's not ultimately necessary..

Comment: Only binary download I found is win32 dll. There is also shared library for ubuntu, but I have feeling that using shared libs in D is harder (the ubuntu package version is also year old).

Comment: Linking to C-based shared libs isn't harder (it's impossible to create a D-based shared library, but that's another matter). I've updated the answer, please see :)

Comment: As for sqlite binding on wiki4d. All seems pretty unmaintained and obsolete for me.

Answer (score 10):

As long as you have the sqlite3 development package installed, you can just call `dmd test.d -L-lsqlite3` -- no need for an absolute path.

A nice alternative is the `lib` pragma:

```
pragma(lib, "sqlite3");

import std.stdio, std.string, etc.c.sqlite3;

void main () {
    sqlite3* db;
    auto ret = sqlite3_open (toStringz("mydb.s3db"), &db);
    writeln (ret);
}
```

With that in place, you can just say `dmd test.d`.

I can't reproduce your issue with `-ldl`, but that could also be added as a pragma directive.

Answer (score 1):

Latest phobos contains a quite up-to-date SQLite binding now.

See phobos/etc/c/sqlite3.d

Comment: I now that :) it is mentioned in my question. But I cannot build the executable without linking sqlite object file - wich is not include in dmd distribution. Manual does yet mention sqlite, I don't know if the sqlite support in phobos is only alpha now ... and whehter I should submit a bug for not including sqlite object file?

Comment: Phobos is never going to include a sqlite object file any more than it's going to include a pthreads object file. Those are shared libraries on your system. The version that you use depends on your system. All Phobos is doing is providing C bindings to sqlite so that you don't have to write them yourself. At some point, it'll probably have a D wrapper over them as well, making it even easier to use sqlite in D, but Phobos doesn't generally include 3rd party libraries in it. And it would be bad if it did. It's not trying to replace your distro's package manager.